# sortByKey in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

New to Spark and Scala. **Trying to sort a word counting example**. [My code is based on this simple example](https://github.com/sryza/simplesparkapp/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkwordcount/SparkWordCount.scala).
I want to sort the results alphabetically by key. If I add the key sort to an RDD:

```
 val wordCounts = names.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortByKey()
```

then I get a compile error:

```
error: No implicit view available from java.io.Serializable => Ordered[java.io.Serializable].
[INFO]     val wordCounts = names.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortByKey()
```

I don't know what the lack of an implicit view means. Can someone tell me how to fix it? I am running the Cloudera 5 Quickstart VM. I think it bundles Spark version 0.9.

#### Source of the Scala job

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"))

    val files = sc.textFile(args(0)).map(_.split(","))

    def f(x:Array[String]) = {
      if (x.length > 3)
        x(3)
      else
        Array("NO NAME")
   }

    val names = files.map(f)

    val wordCounts = names.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortByKey()

    System.out.println(wordCounts.collect().mkString("\n"))
  }
}
```

#### Some (unsorted) output

```
("INTERNATIONAL EYELETS INC",879)
("SHAQUITA SALLEY",865)
("PAZ DURIGA",791)
("TERESSA ALCARAZ",824)
("MING CHAIX",878)
("JACKSON SHIELDS YEISER",837)
("AUDRY HULLINGER",875)
("GABRIELLE MOLANDS",802)
("TAM TACKER",775)
("HYACINTH VITELA",837)
```

Comment: no implicit view means you haven't defined an implicit conversion function between the two types, as for why those are the types it's complaining about not 100% sure, what is the function `f` intended to do, looks like it's mapping out 2 different types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No implicit view means there is no scala function like this defined

```
implicit def SerializableToOrdered(x :java.io.Serializable) = new Ordered[java.io.Serializable](x) //note this function doesn't work
```

The reason this error is coming out is because in your function you are returning two different types with a super type of java.io.Serializable (ones a String the other an Array[String]). Also reduceByKey for obvious reasons requires the key to be an Orderable. Fix it like this

```
object SparkWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"))

    val files = sc.textFile(args(0)).map(_.split(","))

    def f(x:Array[String]) = {
      if (x.length > 3)
        x(3)
      else
        "NO NAME"
    }

    val names = files.map(f)

    val wordCounts = names.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortByKey()

    System.out.println(wordCounts.collect().mkString("\n"))
  }
}
```

Now the function just returns  Strings instead of two different types

Comment: Thanks. I cannot believe I did that. The function f just pulls the fourth elements of an array, if it exists-- I am parsing a CSV file. I was having a little trouble with Scala's anonymous function syntax so I defined a function instead.

Comment: @ahoffer if you explicitly define the return type scala won't try to deduce a type to return, and the error would have been clearer